# Исходники драйвера win7 x64 в win10 x64

Tags: драйвер

Есть такой, считаю незаслуженно заброшенный, проект драйвера ata over ethernet под win.
https://winaoe.org/ и его некоторая оптимизация https://github.com/johannesthoma/winaoe и https://sourceforge.net/projects/aoedisk/.
На данный момент драйвер корректно работает вплоть до win7 (по не полностью подтвержденным данным - win 8.1).
Вопрос к джедаям драйверописательства: "Сильно ли отличается архитектура драйверов win 7  и win 10, что бы имея на руках исходники win 7 можно было бы поправить/дописать/собрать для win 10".
Сам имею не плохой опыт программирования, но с написанием драйвера никогда не сталкивался. Интересует вопрос - стоит ли сейчас браться за изучения вопроса (достаточно объемного, но разового) что бы поправить исходники, или разница в архитектуре слишком большая и всё придется писать почти с нуля, и "игра не стоит свеч"?